# How to plot Circle of radius 1km on Google Maps

Tags: qgis, google-maps, distance, circle

I have circle of radius 1km in QGIS (centered at: -122.69690,58.80688 WGS84, North America), when I export it to Google map it isn't 1km in radius (I checked using the measure tool on Google maps) and the shape isn't a perfect circle as seen below.

On Google maps, North and South direction from the center are more that 1km radius while in East and West direction it is less than 1km.

How can this be fixed?

**In QGIS**
[image]

---

**In Google Maps**

[image]

Comment: @AndreJ I disagree this is a duplicate. Related, yes. Duplicate, no.

Comment: The data's at 59°N which has a meridional convergence of 0.515 (length of a degree of  longitude is half what it is at the equator), plus the projection used by Google Maps is Mercator which has a lot of north-south distortion which at 59°N is 1/0.515.